# How to configure imagick to work with gpu support?

Tags: imagemagick, gpu, imagick

Im usinf the following configuration on amazon AWS p3.2xlarge with 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GV100GL [Tesla V100 SXM2] (rev a1)

Centos 7
PHP7.2

Im trying to force Imagick to work with gpu memory instead of CPU

I have found the following article but im not sure how to implement it

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/opencl.php

can anyone assist ?

convert -version output

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-14 Q16 x86_64 2018-10-25 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

Comment: You have to make sure that ImageMagick was compiled with OpenCL and you need to have compatible graphics hardware. Use `convert -version` and see if it lists OpenCL in the Features line.

Comment: I have added the output to the question.. how can i add OpenCL support ?

Comment: Your compile of ImageMagick 7.0.8.14 does not include OpenCL. You will have to recompile with OpenCL enabled. See https://imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#distributed

Comment: Usually OpenCL installs automatically if your hardware is compatible.

Comment: Im using https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/p3/ so it has GPU installed

Comment: I am not an expert on installing OpenCL. I thought it installed automatically with ImageMagick if the hardware is compatible. My only other though is to compile ImageMagick from source and add --enable OpenCL to your .configure command. But since you are on amazon aws, it may be out of your control and they may have disabled it. Check with amazon aws. Sorry I know little about amazon aws.